# Android Studio missing libXrender.so.1

Tags: android, android-studio, debian

I've installed Android Studio on debian Linux (sid). According to the [installation instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html), I have run

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

but upon start, Android Studio crashes, complaining about missing libXrender.so.1:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/phihag/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/amd64/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
        at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
        at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:101)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:74)
        ... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:594)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:198)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:174)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:153)
        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation instructions are incomplete and assume the (x86_**64**) system already has various common graphical libraries installed. You also need to install:

```
sudo apt install libxrender-dev libxtst6 libfreetype6
```

Comment: I needed to install `libxrender-dev`, fwiw.